# How to get a screen reader to read a disabled element using aria?

Tags: html, wai-aria

I'm trying to get a screen reader to read the values of number spinners/ text boxes that have been disabled so that they are un-editable. The value of these boxes is important in context, but the screen reader (JAWS in this case) only reads the values of the widgets as 'unavailable'. I tried setting aria-required='true' to no such luck. Is there any other way to get a screen reader to say these values?

Ex:

```
<input id='exampleInput' disabled='true' aria-required='true'>1</input>
```

Comment: I think you need to set it to readonly instead.

Comment: I can't set the element to readonly, as that will interfere with other javascript. I tried aria-readonly, but disabled supercedes that.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is using javascript to cancel changes to the input.

Comment: It's not really about the changes to the input, its just that the value of the input box (in the example '1') is not being read.

Comment: Typically the solution is to use readonly in stead of disabled (for the reason you mention).

Comment: The problem with readonly is the value will get passed in the form.

"a readonly element is just not editable, but gets sent when the according form submits. a disabled element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit. another difference is that readonly elements can be focused (and getting focused when "tabbing" through a form) while disabled elements can't."

Comment: What about moving the value into a hidden input?

Comment: _“The problem with readonly is the value will get passed in the form.”_ – well then set them to `disabled` only when the form gets submitted …

Answer (score 3):

Using the Read-only attribute is the right option here.

if this will mess with you JavaScript then I suggest changing your JavaScript so that it will check for something other then the disabled attribute.

this can be done by using a Css Class, or by adding a new attribute, or you can add a new field to the DOM object and use that.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem recently, my solution was to use some informational text for all the disabled buttons, which is only viewable by screen readers. I used a button element so it still retains a place in the tab order, so if a screen reader user is tabbing through the form it will be announced, you need to implement some code to remove the elements from the DOM once the actual inputs are enabled.

The hidden element announces as “data value goes here element disabled” when tested with NVDA, you can use whatever text you want, obviously.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="myDisabledElement" disabled="disabled">

<button aria-disabled=”true” class="sr-only">
     data value goes here element disabled
</button>
```

CSS

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

You can see it in abstract action here: http://codepen.io/chris-hore/pen/LEKyeM